# How to insert LaTeX commands through LuaLaTeX callbacks?

Tags: luatex, luacode, callback, penalty

I would like to encourage LaTeX to break a line or page at the end of a sentence, after one of the following punctuation marks: "." ; "!" and "?".

I would like to put a penalty of -50 to slightly encourage line breaks at the end of a sentence and a penalty of -200 to encourage a bit more page breaks at the end of a sentence, because I think it is more disturbing for the reader.

I thought of creating a command to apply the appropriate penalty depending on whether you are in horizontal or vertical mode and then using the power of lualatex and using its `callback` to insert this command after each of the punctuation marks concerned.

My problem is how to insert this command. I can insert penalties, but only with a single value that doesn't distinguish between penalty in horizontal mode (-50) and penalty in vertical mode (-200).

Do you know how to insert LaTeX commands through LuaLaTeX callbacks?

(I tried `node.insert_after(head, head, tex.sprint("\test"))` but it did not work)

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode, lipsum}

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \ifvmode%
        \penalty -200
    \else%
        \penalty -50
    \fi%
    \space%
}

\begin{luacode}
local GLYPH = node.id("glyph") -- print('GLYPH value: ', GLYPH)
local GLUE = node.id("glue") -- print('GLUE value: ', GLUE)

local end_sentence_spacing = function (head)
    while head do
        if (head.id == GLYPH) then
            if head.prev then
                if unicode.utf8.match(unicode.utf8.char(head.char), "[.!?]") then
                    if (head.next.id == GLUE) then
                        local p = node.new("penalty")
                        p.penalty = -50
                        node.insert_after(head, head, p)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        head = head.next
    end
    return true
end

function end_sentence_spacing_enable ()
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_shaping_filter", end_sentence_spacing, "endofsentencespacing")
end
\end{luacode}

\long\def\EndSentenceSpacingEnable{\directlua{end_sentence_spacing_enable()}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\clearpage\EndSentenceSpacingEnable{}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you are followig `.|?` you are always in an hlist so you will never be in vmode